# Area 51's 'reduce ads' privilege on discuss redirects to 404

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, privileges, 404-not-found

On [discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/help/privileges](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges), there is one privilege, *reduce ads*:

[image: 'reduce ads']

Clicking this goes to

- [discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/reduced-ads](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/reduced-ads)

  …which redirects to…
- [area51.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/reduced-ads](http://area51.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/reduced-ads)

  …which is a 404.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why that privilege was there; discuss.Area51 is more or less a child-meta site, and privileges on child metas are generally the same as on the parent site.

...which is a whole 'nother can of worms on Area51, but... I digress.

You shouldn't see any privileges now if you happen to browse to https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges